# Slow query in slow query log

Tags: magento2, sql

SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`description`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`s watch_image`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`featured`, `e`.`groupdeal_status`, `e`.`groupdeal_status_value`, `e`.`groupdeal_datetime_from`, `e`.`groupdeal_datetime_to`, `e`.`is_ebayaffiliate`, `e`.`merchant_name`, `e`.`merchant_name_value`, `e`.`aw_deep_link`, `e`.`merchant_deep_link`, `e`.`cpsp_enable`, `e`.`cpsp_expand_prices`, `e`.`cpsp_show_lowest`, `e`.`cpsp_show_maxregular`, `e`.`cpsp_show_stock`, `e`.`cpsp_show_stock_value`, `e`.`cpsp_enable_tier`, `e`.`cpsp_show_last_price`, `e`.`cpsp_use_preselection`, `e`.`cpsp_use_tier_lowest`, `e`.`cpsp_update_fields`, `e`.`m2_sofas_colour`, `e`.`m2_sofas_colour_value`, `e`.`m2_sofa_width`, `e`.`m2_sofa_width_value`, `e`.`m2_tables_racks_colour`, `e`.`m2_tables_racks_colour_value`, `e`.`s_category_name`, `e`.`s_category_name_value`, `e`.`other_Essentials_colours`, `e`.`amtoolkit_canonical`, `e`.`on_sale`, `e`.`is_black_friday_product`, `e`.`black_friday_price`, `e`.`product_fitting_instruction_video`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered) AS `ordered`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
LEFT JOIN `sales_order_item` ON e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id AND sales_order_item.store_id=1
LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (e.entity_id IN (60001, 442, 120, 55080, 60259, 156, 26956, 26727, 14533, 130, 12601, 27075, 14566, 59929, 162, 79886, 51978, 55081, 12594, 12577, 60258, 143, 146, 12585)) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` ORDER BY FIELD(e.entity_id,60001,442,120,55080,60259,156,26956,26727,14533,130,12601,27075,14566,59929,162,79886,51978,55081,12594,12577,60258,143,146,12585) ASC, `ordered` desc, `entity_id` ASC;

i am getting this query regularly in my slow sql log what will be the solution?

## Time: 2022-07-18T13:51:28.196046Z

## Query_time: 15.366027  Lock_time: 0.000764 Rows_sent: 24  Rows_examined: 8224237

SET timestamp=1658152288;

Comment: Please consider posting the last 500 lines of your Slow Query Log for us to see what you are dealing with.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of  EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query);SHOW WARNINGS;    with this information we should be able to detect missing indexes.